# Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview IntelliSense can't open F# modules?

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2012

Bug or Am I doing something wrong ?

[image]

```
Error   13  The namespace or module 'BModel' is not defined
Error   12  The namespace or module 'Connector' is not defined
Error   11  The namespace or module 'Work' is not defined
```

But compiling with it...

command line :

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft F#\v4.0\fsc.exe -o:obj\Debug\TCPBattle.dll -g --debug:full --noframework --define:DEBUG --define:TRACE --doc:D:\opc_boi\trunk\Debug\TCPBattle.XML --optimize+ --tailcalls- -r:"C:\Program Files\FSharp-2.0.0.0\v4.0\bin\FSharp.Core.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Core.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Numerics.dll" --target:library --warn:3 --warnaserror:76 --vserrors --LCID:1033 --utf8output --fullpaths --flaterrors "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.fs" Hex.fs Model.fs DeviceModel.fs Native.fs C.fs Core.fs Connector.fs Work.fs Battle.fs 
BOIConnector -> D:\opc_boi\trunk\Debug\TCPBattle.dll
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what caused such trouble. And there is same error on VS2010

this :

```
// エラーが発生
// 停止
```

**Japanese comments breaks IntelliSense.**

Comment: Should be reported to MS as a bug, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're in Battle.fs in the screenshot, and presumably e.g. Work.fs contains the Work module, and it is above Battle.fs... if you right click the file in solution explorer and select properties, is the 'BuildAction' set to 'Compile'?  What happens when you compile (what command-line is sent to fsc.exe in the output window)?  (Have you tried closing VS and restarting?)

Comment: Yes, it's 'Compile' check question update for command line and it's compiles well. Just I don't like Intellisense errors.

Comment: after all there is no error on " = new Connector() " line, but Connector type is from Connector module.

Comment: Try restarting VS, this seems like a bug.

Comment: Hm, sounds like just a bug then.  These are preview bits, I'm sure there are many little bugs, it sounds like this one is thankfully a mere 'annoyance' rather than a blocker.

Comment: I don't think that could be not tested. I will try new project and ela
borate on what is causing this bug.